# Insert an Object into an Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to insert an Excel document into an Excel worksheet. I can do this manually by the following steps;

Insert / Text / Object / Create From File (tick Display as Icon) / Browse.
I then select the file and insert the document.

I would like to do this via a macro. (The recorder won't let you record it.)

This code I have basically is Insert / Text / Object

```
Sub ShowInsertObj()
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertObject).Show
End Sub
```

I would like to add code so that a directory (lets say C:\temp) will automatically be selected and display as icon will be ticked - instead of applying the above steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if exactly what you wanted is possible, but you might want to use `GetOpenFilename` and `.OLEObjects` instead of `xlDialogInsertObject`.

```
Sub ShowInsertObj()

Dim Fl As Variant
Dim Filename As String

'Set your drive
ChDrive "C:"
ChDir "C:\temp"

'Grab your file filtered for Excel files
Fl = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xls; *.xlsm),*.xls;*.xslm")
If Fl = False Then Exit Sub

' To display the filename only and not the path 

Filename = Mid$(F1, InStrRev(F1, "\") + 1, Len(F1))

'Add as object to the worksheet
Sheet1.OLEObjects.Add Filename:=Filename, Link:=True, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:="EXCEL.EXE", IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:=Filename

End Sub
```

<sub>**Note:** I used `FileFilter` since you said you wanted to insert an Excel file</sub>